# Is it possible to turn off mouse middle button light?

Tags: mouse

I'm using a CD-R King M series mouse. Is there some way I can turn off the middle mouse button light? My computer runs Windows 7.

Comment: In order for someone to answer that question, you would need to specify the brand and model of mouse and your operating system.

Comment: windows 7, cd-r king m series

Comment: Unlikely - the light is probably the same one that does the sensing of movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a general way:

1. Download [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), a great freeware script language.
2. Install it, together with its editor (SciTe4AutoHotKey).
3. Click *File* > *New*.
4. Use the following code:

   ```
   #InstallMouseHook
   MButton::
   ```
5. *File* > *Save*, select a name (e.g. `mouse.ahk`)
6. Put a shortcut for this file in your **Startup** folder.
7. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 2):

A little hardware hacking could help.

I don't know details about your mouse but a little screwdriver and a little (more) patience could let you find out what produces the light (probably @Matt Jenkins is right) and if you can turn it off or just use a little black sello tape to hide it.

Have fun :)