# Mouse light doesn't turn off when computer is off

Tags: usb, motherboard, bios, mouse, shutdown

I've bought a [Coolermaster devastator bundle](http://www.coolermaster-usa.com/product.php?product_id=10064) with my new PC. When i shut down the computer, the light on the mouse never turns off. The keyboard lights are off. Both peripherals are plugged with USB. My motherboard is a [GigaByte GA-Z97M-DS3H](http://www.gigabyte.fr/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4964#ov)

Any idea why the mouse never shut down? Maybe an option in the BIOS?

[image]

**Update**:

After reading the [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z97m-ds3h_e.pdf), i didn't found a jumper to deactivate the functionality.
However, it talk about the ON/OFF charge (page 8) in the "Unique Features" part, which is related to a software called AppCenter. I've installed it but the ON/OFF charge is the only features listed in the manual I don't have in the app (tried to explore EasyTune, EZ setup, Smart timeclock, etc... nothing helped).

I've also check the options in the BIOS but i didn't found anything related to that problem.

The BIOS is up-to-date, I can't see what I can do now.

Comment: read http://superuser.com/questions/257423/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-mouse-middle-button-light and http://superuser.com/questions/430857/how-to-disable-power-to-the-mouse-and-keyboard-after-shutdown

Comment: The first link doesn't help but the second one maybe can. I'll check on the manual if I found this +5v AUX jumper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've finally found the option into the BIOS.

I've set ErP to Enabled:

> Determines whether to let the system consume least power in S5
>   (shutdown) state. (Default: Disabled) Note: When this item is set to
>   Enabled, the following functions will become unavailable: PME event
>   wake  up, power on by mouse, power on by keyboard, and wake on LAN.

Comment: Thanks I have the Same Devastator Combo, now i know why my mouse pulls off an all-nighter every night ;)

Comment: It does not work on my Gigabyte Z97X-UD3H-CF. Which kind of USB ports should I use for my keyboard and mouse?